# Get sum(a+b-c)and some individual fields like select name from table?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT (
        SELECT SUM(qty)
        FROM sk_lgr_hd
        WHERE item_id = 4
            AND tra_type = 'OS'
            AND dept_id = 7
        ) + (
        SELECT SUM(qty)
        FROM sk_lgr_hd
        WHERE item_id = 4
            AND tra_type = 'IR'
            AND dept_id = 7
        ) - (
        SELECT SUM(qty)
        FROM sk_lgr_hd
        WHERE item_id = 4
            AND tra_type = 'IS'
            AND dept_id = 7
        )
```

I can  Get sum still i need to get dept_id,tra_type,id,..
i need  some thing like this.

```
sum dept_id  id
 20   2       3
```

Comment: i just want to add. select tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id from sk_lgr_hd ) to above query

Comment: So are you looking for a `Group By` ??

Comment: some how even tried with group by also no luck.

Comment: Try this `select sum(qty) qty, tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id
from sk_lgr_hd
where item_id=4 and dept_id = 7
group by tra_type,tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id`

Comment: select(select SUM(qty)qty, tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id from sk_lgr_hd where item_id = 4 and tra_type = 'OS' and dept_id = 7 group by tra_type,tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id  ) +(select SUM(qty)qty, tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id from sk_lgr_hd where item_id = 4 and tra_type = 'IR' and dept_id = 7  group by tra_type,tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id) - (select SUM(qty)qty, tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id from sk_lgr_hd where item_id = 4 and tra_type = 'IS' and dept_id = 7 group by tra_type,tra_id,date,dept_id,item_id,stock_id)

Comment: as we know  subquery will return only one column so getting error

Comment: The code you posted ain't the one that I commented

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95902/discussion-between-satish-kilari-and-vivek-s).

Comment: Don't post code in comments. **Edit** your question